# Unable to install semPLS package

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the semPLS package on my new MacBook but I get the error:

```
install.packages("semPLS")

Warning in install.packages :
   package 'semPLS' is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

My RStudio is Version R Studio-2022.02.1 Build 461
I've also tried using the earlier version of R 0.99.486 but still have the same problem.

I've used this quite often in the past. It is only when I tried to install the package  on my new laptop, that I can't.
I tried looking for the package on cran and cannot find it there. Any advice on how I can locate and install semPLS?

Comment: Looks like it is no longer on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/semPLS/index.html

Comment: thanks- was hoping someone would know if there is an alternative

Comment: Have you used lavaaan or seminr? seminr might be close to what smpls used to achieve https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seminr/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can install it using the function `install_github()` from package `"devtools"`

install `devtools`:

```
install.packages("devtools") 
library(devtools)
```

install `semPLS`:

```
install_github("cran/semPLS")
```